# lirc IR receiver problem

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to make IR receiver - tsop 1136 work with openELEC and control with my TV remote.
Got all the parts, updates, lirc, configurations done, but I have a problem.
When starting :: `dmesg | grep lirc_rpi` I get ::

```
[   35.442930] lirc_rpi: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   35.450315] lirc_rpi lirc_rpi.0: lirc_dev: driver lirc_rpi registered at minor = 0
[   35.450340] lirc_rpi: driver registered!
[   36.407388] lirc_rpi: auto-detected active high receiver on GPIO pin 18
```

On executing ::   `mode2 -d /dev/lirc0` I get non-stop spaces and pulses like this::

```
space 9086
space 10907
space 50
space 9079
space 10916
pulse 35
space 9088
space 10961
pulse 29
space 9
space 9090
space 10905
pulse 50
space 9088
space 10950
pulse 49
space 9073
space 10971
pulse 33
space 9030
space 10964
pulse 48
space 9055
space 10963
pulse 30
pulse 11
space 9056
space 10980
pulse 50
space 9041
```

And it goes on and on and on, without pressing any buttons of remote. Also if I disconnect the cable from the data pin of the IR receiver, it also doesn't stop. If I remove the wire from the PIN18 of the raspberry it stops, but if I touch it with my finger it starts again.
Please help me out...

Comment: Something is not grounded properly? Put in other words, the sense pin is floating giving you junk.